# How to explain differences between used_bytes, alloc_bytes & the actual size?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, memory, dynamic-sql

I estimated the size of an index like this:

```
variable used_bytes number
variable alloc_bytes number
exec dbms_space.create_index_cost('create index testCommune_idx on commune(nom_com)', :used_bytes, :alloc_bytes);

print :used_bytes -- prints 472134
print :alloc_bytes -- prints 983040
```

Then, I created it :

```
CREATE INDEX testCommune_idx ON commune(nom_com);
```

And I selected his actual size in the table `user_segments`

```
SELECT trim(to_char(bytes, '999,999,999')) actual_bytes
FROM user_segments 
WHERE segment_name = 'TESTCOMMUNE_IDX';
-- return 2,097,152
```

How to you explain such differences?

- USED_BYTES : 472134
- ALLOC_BYTES :  983040
- ACTUAL_BYTES: 2,097,152

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is better asked on dba stack, I requested to move it

Comment: read this article https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/index-size/